# How can I play audio in reverse with web audio API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-audio-api

How can I play audio in reverse with the [web audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html)? I can't seem to find anything in the API docs...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var context = new AudioContext(),
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'path/to/audio.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.addEventListener('load', function(){
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer){
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        Array.prototype.reverse.call( buffer.getChannelData(0) );
        Array.prototype.reverse.call( buffer.getChannelData(1) );
        source.buffer = buffer;
    });
});
```

It's a super simple example - but the point is basically that you can grab the `Float32Array` instance for each channel in the AudioBuffer and reverse them.

Comment: This does work, thanks. I was actually looking for something more like setting playbackRate to a negative number so I can play something forward and backward easily from the same point in the clip, but since you answered the question with a valid (and working!) response, I'll accept it!

Comment: Yeah, I figured you were probably looking for something a little less hacky, but this was the only approach I could come up with. For what it's worth, it's probably still possible to build some code around this approach that'll do what you want  - but I haven't actually tried reversing the buffer on the fly, so I can't say for sure. Either way, it's good to see other devs playing with the Web Audio API. Hopefully some decent documentation will start showing up in the next few months.

Answer (score 6):

if you have an AudioBufferSourceNode element:

```
audioBufferSourceNode.playbackRate = -1;
```

**-EDIT-**

Webkit doesn't have that feature.

Source: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69725

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. The minValue on the playbackRate AudioParam is 0. When I set it to a value lower than 0 it appears to playback at the defaultValue (which is 1).

Comment: Okey... it's an actual bug it webkit :(

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69725

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<audio>` element of html5 and set `playbackRate` property to negative value.

In Javascript you can do the following

```
var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]; 
song.playbackRate = -1;
```

Comment: The audio tag does not perform to my requirements, which is why I need to use the web audio API specifically.

Comment: The playback rate should be between 0.5 and 4.0. Negative values don't work yet. [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/WebAudio_playbackRate_explained)

Answer (score 1):

```
playbackRate = -1.0;
```

works in Safari (9.1.2) now!