# how can I reverse playback in web audio API but keep a forward version as well?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

To my knowledge, the Web Audio API in google Chrome (v21) does not support the following:

```
    source.playbackRate.value = -1;
```

I very much wish! I will be patient, but in the meantime, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874167/how-can-i-play-audio-in-reverse-with-web-audio-api) has a nice alternative solution.  I have adopted it to try and reverse my own audio samples loaded from a [loaded bufferlist](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/browse/trunk/samples/audio/doc/loading-sounds.html), hoping that I can have both a forward and reversed version of each loaded buffer, like so:

```
    function finishedLoading(bufferList)  {
        for (var it = 0; it < this.urlList.length; ++it) {  
            storedBuffer[it] = bufferList[it]; // assign bufferList to globals
            storedBufferR[it] = bufferList[it];

            // attempt to reverse storedBufferR only ...
            Array.prototype.reverse.call( storedBufferR[it].getChannelData(0) );
            Array.prototype.reverse.call( storedBufferR[it].getChannelData(1) ); 
        }
    }
```

The above function indeed reverses playback, however it reverses both 'storedbufferR' *and* 'storedbuffer' such that all buffers are reversed!

So here is where I get lost... I understand that Array.protoype affects all arrays, so I suppose I can see how 'storedBuffer' is affected by a reverse method on 'storedBufferR'. EDIT: the reverse method only affects the array in question

But is it possible to rewrite the above function to ensure array.protoype affects only the stored buffer I want reversed? If not, is there another way to go about storing both a forward and reversed version?

Comment: It looks more like `storedBuffer[it] === storedBufferR[it]` (as in, they share the same reference). Look into creating a `new AudioContext()` for `storedBufferR`

Comment: hmm... you are probably right. But a new AudioContext requires me to load in my sound files again, which doesn't strike me as efficient. But I see what you mean: there is only one buffer to manipulate.

Comment: @o1sound "I understand that Array.protoype affects all arrays, so I suppose I can see how 'storedBuffer' is affected by a reverse method on 'storedBufferR'." <-- It's important to note that this is not what happens at all. Using .reverse() through `Array.prototype.reverse.call()` is just a way to call the .reverse() function and have it use as its internal "this" value whatever you pass as the first argument to .call() (in this case a Float32Array). A Float32Array doesn't have .reverse() as one of its methods but it's "array-like" enough for Array.prototype.reverse() to be able to handle it.

Comment: @o1sound ...continued: So, the reason `storedBuffer` is affected by calling `Array.prototype.reverse.call()` on `storedBufferR` is because both variables are referencing the same value, as sshac mentioned.

Comment: @Alexander nice! thanks. I was teetering between the two ideas, and I'm glad it works as you described.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment about the two AudioBuffers sharing the same reference was on the right track, but the solution isn't to create a new AudioContext; rather, you just need to create a new AudioBuffer and clone the underlying Float32Arrays that hold the actual audio samples.

For example, this function would clone an AudioBuffer:

```
function cloneAudioBuffer(audioBuffer){
    var channels = [],
        numChannels = audioBuffer.numberOfChannels;

    //clone the underlying Float32Arrays
    for (var i = 0; i < numChannels; i++){
        channels[i] = new Float32Array(audioBuffer.getChannelData(i));
    }

    //create the new AudioBuffer (assuming AudioContext variable is in scope)
    var newBuffer = context.createBuffer(
                        audioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
                        audioBuffer.length,
                        audioBuffer.sampleRate
                    );

    //copy the cloned arrays to the new AudioBuffer
    for (var i = 0; i < numChannels; i++){
        newBuffer.getChannelData(i).set(channels[i]);
    }

    return newBuffer;
}
```

Then, to modify the above...

```
function finishedLoading(bufferList)  {
    for (var it = 0; it < this.urlList.length; ++it) {  
        storedBuffer[it] = bufferList[it]; // assign bufferList to globals
        storedBufferR[it] = cloneAudioBuffer(bufferList[it]);

        // attempt to reverse storedBufferR only ...
        Array.prototype.reverse.call( storedBufferR[it].getChannelData(0) );
        Array.prototype.reverse.call( storedBufferR[it].getChannelData(1) ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was hoping the solution would be.