# HTML Audio - negative playbackRate values not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm playing with audio in HTML and JS/JQuery in order to build a audio player.  I have Play, Pause, and Fast Forward working, but not Rewind or Backwards.  In the [W3Schools Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp) it says:

> *playbackspeed*   Indicates the current playback speed of the audio/video. Example values:
>
> -1.0 is backwards

So the code that I've written is as follows:

```
<audio id="player">
    <source src="http://www.dkedomain.com/public/podcast/shows/the-domain-episode-09.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<button class="rewind">Rewind</button>
<button class="play">Play</button>
<button class="pause">Pause</button>
<button class="twotimes">2x</button>
<button class="forward">Fast Forward</button>

<script>

    var player = document.getElementById('player');;
    player.load();

    $('button.rewind').click(function(){
        player.playbackRate = -1.0;
    });

    $('button.play').click(function(){
        player.play();
        console.log(player.currentTime);
    });

    $('button.pause').click(function(){
        player.pause();
        console.log(player.currentTime);
    });

    $('button.twotimes').click(function(){
        player.playbackRate = 2.0;
    });

    $('button.forward').click(function(){
        player.playbackRate = 3.0;
    });

</script>
```

How do I get this to work as documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Stack Overflow answer for [How can I play audio in reverse with web audio API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875011/6263819) shows that setting the `audio.playbackrate = -1` will work, except in WebKit-based browsers.  Chrome and Safari will ignore this setting, although other browsers may support it.

An interesting thing to do might be to implement Rewind to go back a few seconds, kind of like it does with some DVR players.  Something like this might work:

```
$('button.rewind').click(function() {
    var currentTime = player.currentTime;
    player.currentTime = (currentTime >= 3.0) ? currentTime - 3.0 : 0;
});
```

You could do the same with Fast Forward, as well, for symmetry of the features.  Your 2x button is a good "play faster" solution, which is a good  complement to this approach.

I have created a jsFiddle for this, with various other changes that you might like: https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/11n63g3w/

Comment: That would make sense! Thanks!